# Accessing Static Data in Angular 4 Spec

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I got and `angular 4 component` for which i want to write some `specs` in the component itself i got `public searchResponse`

and following is my spec file

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

import {myreducer} from '../reducers/myreducer';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],

      imports: [
        StoreModule.provideStore({
          myreducer
        }),

      ],

    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();



  });

  it('should create', () => {


  });
});
```

Now the problem i got is simple when i run `ng test` i end up with a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchResponse' of undefined`

The searchReponse is in the `AppComponent` as follows

`export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public searchReponse ;
......`

Any ideas what may be causing this issue? How can i just pass the searchReponse as an object if possible even?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by hard coding the service response in the spec as below,

In the `describe` block declare a parameter as below,

```
let searchResponse = [
                { 'name': 'ab' },
                { 'name': 'ab' },
                { 'name': 'ab' }
];
```

When the search button is clicked you can validate the test case using the below statement

```
it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    button.click();
    expect(component.searchResponse).toBe(searchResponse);

});
```

Comment: the `searchReponse` in the `component` is assigned in the `constructor` not sure if that should make a difference. The above code did not work though

Comment: In the `ngOnInit` in the component the searchResponse gets assigned data from a service that reads a json file like in `searchResponse = this.getJsonDataService.getData()` When i replaced the `getJsonDataService.getData()` with an `object` it worked. Sorry for not being clear enough, it is the first Unit Test i ever write in my life.